# decrypting using openssl api with iter, default pad and salt

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, salt

I am trying to decrypting using openssl api functions instead of direct system command, I have encrypted through the system command using this

Edit: Solution at below answer by me.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 310000 -md sha256 -salt -in file.run -out encrypted_data.enc -pass pass:Password!
```

Before this I have created my symetrickeys and used those for the above.

This is my code used for the decrypting with the system command

```
bool CryptoProcessor::_decryptData(Any &response)
{
  String tempPrefix = String("/tmp/aaaa-") + uuid();

  std::ifstream input(_inputFile, std::ios::binary); //the input file is the encrypted file which had signature and symetric key on top of it
  input.seekg(SIGNATURE_SIZE + KEY_SIZE, std::ios::beg);

  String encryptedDataFileName = tempPrefix + ".encrypted-data";
  OutputFileStream encryptedDataFile;
  encryptedDataFile.open(encryptedDataFileName, std::ios::binary);

  char chunk[CHUNK_SIZE];
  while (!input.eof())
  {
    input.read(chunk, CHUNK_SIZE);
    int bytesRead = input.gcount();
    encryptedDataFile.write(chunk, bytesRead);
  }
  encryptedDataFile.close();
  input.close();

  String runFileName = tempPrefix + ".run";
  String command = String("openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -pbkdf2 -iter 310000 -p -md sha256 -salt -pass pass:") + _symmetricKey + " -in '" + encryptedDataFileName + "' -out '" + runFileName +"'";
//I added -p to understand how the salt , key and iv are there and identify them as coming right or wrong when i use the openssl api
  logger(LOG_INFO) << command << endl;
  ANY_ASSERT(system(command.c_str()) == 0, "Decryption failed")
  return true;
}
```

I am trying like this to decrypt  it using api but code succcesfully decrypts the file but it is giving the wrong file i.e decrypting not done properly, I checked the salt, key and IV of these in the below code, i found those are very different and not the expected.

```
    // Create an OpenSSL BIO object for input and output
    BIO *bio_in = BIO_new_file(encryptedDataFileName.c_str(), "rb");
    BIO *bio_out = BIO_new_file(runFileName.c_str(), "wb");

    if (!bio_in || !bio_out)
    {
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to open input/output BIOs" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Create an EVP decryption context
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx)
    {
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to create cipher context" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Set the AES-256-CBC cipher
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr) != 1)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to initialize decryption context" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0); // Disable padding

    // Set the symmetric key using PBKDF2
    unsigned char derivedKey[32]; // 256 bits for AES-256
    int iterCount = 310000;
    logger(LOG_INFO) << "Iterations: " << iterCount << std::endl;
    const char *passphrase = _symmetricKey.c_str();
    logger(LOG_INFO) << "Passphrase: " << _symmetricKey << std::endl;
    unsigned char salt[PKCS5_SALT_LEN];
    RAND_bytes(salt, sizeof(salt))

    unsigned char iv[16];
    RAND_bytes(iv, sizeof(iv));

    if (PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(passphrase, -1, salt, sizeof(salt), iterCount, EVP_sha256(), 32, derivedKey) != 1)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to derive encryption key using PBKDF2" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    logger(LOG_INFO) << "Derived Key: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        logger(LOG_INFO) << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(derivedKey[i]);
    }
    logger(LOG_INFO) << std::dec << std::endl;

    // Set the key and IV for decryption
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, nullptr, nullptr, derivedKey, nullptr) != 1)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to set decryption key and IV" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
```

Help me, In writing the code for the given system command of openssl with api.

Answer (score 0):

Decryption MUST use the same values for salt and IV as encryption used, but you're generating new random values which will be wrong with overwhelming probability. `openssl enc` stores the salt at offset 8-15 in the file (read it from there), and only offset 16-last is actually ciphertext (decrypt only that part); it also derives *both* key and IV (if the mode uses it, which CBC does) from password+salt, so do the PBKDF2 call to generate 48 bytes and use the first 32 for the key and the last 16 for the IV. Also for a block mode like CBC `enc` by default uses PKCS5/7 padding, so by turning off padding during decryption you will add some garbage bytes to your plaintext.

PS: if you declare `inBuf outBuf` as array of `unsigned char` (not just `char`) you don't need to the ugly casts, and as a bonus it more accurately describes what is in at least the encrypted file and potentially the decrypted one, namely raw data that is not actually characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dave_thompson_085
The message from him helped me solving this, This is the solution when you are encryption is having salt, Iter and default pad value.

```
bool CryptoProcessor::_decryptData(Any &response)
{
    String tempPrefix = String("/tmp/aaaa-") + uuid();

    std::ifstream input(_inputFile, std::ios::binary);
    input.seekg(SIGNATURE_SIZE + KEY_SIZE, std::ios::beg);

    String encryptedDataFileName = tempPrefix + ".encrypted-data";
    OutputFileStream encryptedDataFile;
    encryptedDataFile.open(encryptedDataFileName, std::ios::binary);

    unsigned char chunk[CHUNK_SIZE];
    
    String runFileName = tempPrefix + ".run";


    // Create an EVP decryption context
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx)
    {
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to create cipher context" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Set the AES-256-CBC cipher
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr) != 1)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to initialize decryption context" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Create BIOs using file pointers
    FILE *inFile = fopen(encryptedDataFileName.c_str(), "rb");
    FILE *outFile = fopen(runFileName.c_str(), "wb");

    BIO *bio_in = BIO_new_fp(inFile, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    BIO *bio_out = BIO_new_fp(outFile, BIO_NOCLOSE);

    if (!bio_in || !bio_out)
    {
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to create input/output BIOs" << std::endl;
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        return false;
    }


    // Derive the key using PBKDF2
    unsigned char derivedKey[32]; // 256 bits for AES-256
    //unsigned char encryptionKey[KEY_SIZE]; 
    int iterCount = 310000;
    const char *passphrase = _symmetricKey.c_str();
    logger(LOG_INFO) << passphrase << std::endl;

    unsigned char salt[PKCS5_SALT_LEN];
    unsigned char block[16]; // Read the full 16 bytes
    if (BIO_read(bio_in, block, sizeof(block)) != sizeof(block))
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to read salt from input file" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Extract the last 8 bytes as the salt
    memcpy(salt, block + 8, PKCS5_SALT_LEN);

    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc();
    int iklen = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(cipher);
    int ivlen = EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(cipher);

    unsigned char key[iklen];
    unsigned char iv[ivlen];
    unsigned char keyivpair[iklen + ivlen];

    // Derive the key and IV using PBKDF2
    if (!PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(passphrase, -1, salt, sizeof(salt), iterCount, EVP_sha256(), iklen + ivlen, keyivpair))
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to derive encryption key using PBKDF2" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Copy the derived key and IV to their respective buffers
    memcpy(key, keyivpair, iklen);
    memcpy(iv, keyivpair + iklen, ivlen);

    // Set the key and IV for decryption
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, cipher, NULL, key, iv) != 1)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Failed to set decryption key and IV" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    //Use for checking the salt and IV values if anything goes wrong, verify using the command line by passing arg -p to compare the values of the below
    // printf("Salt: ");
    // for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(salt); ++i)
    // {
    //     printf("%02X", salt[i]);
    // }
    // printf("\n");

    // printf("Derived Key: ");
    // for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(derivedKey); ++i)
    // {
    //     printf("%02X", derivedKey[i]);
    // }
    // printf("\n");

    // printf("IV: ");
    // for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(iv); ++i)
    // {
    //     printf("%02X", iv[i]);
    // }
    // printf("\n");

    // Perform the decryption
    unsigned char inBuf[CHUNK_SIZE];
    unsigned char outBuf[CHUNK_SIZE];

    int outLen;
    while (true)
    {
        int bytesRead = BIO_read(bio_in, inBuf, CHUNK_SIZE);
        if (bytesRead <= 0)
            break;

        if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, outBuf, &outLen, inBuf, bytesRead) != 1)
        {
          
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            BIO_free_all(bio_in);
            BIO_free_all(bio_out);
            logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Decryption failed" << std::endl;
            
            return false;
        }

        BIO_write(bio_out, outBuf, outLen);
    }

    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, outBuf, &outLen) != 1)
    {
        unsigned long error = ERR_get_error();
        char errorString[256];
        ERR_error_string_n(error, errorString, sizeof(errorString));
        logger(LOG_ERROR) << "Decryption finalization failed: " << errorString << std::endl;
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        BIO_free_all(bio_in);
        BIO_free_all(bio_out);
        return false;
    }

    BIO_write(bio_out, outBuf, outLen);

    // Clean up
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    BIO_free_all(bio_in);
    BIO_free_all(bio_out);

    logger(LOG_INFO) << "Decryption Done" << std::endl;
    remove(encryptedDataFileName.c_str());
    
    return true;
}
```